# modules concerning Fermat's little thoerem

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Suppose $2^a \equiv 2^b\pmod{101}$. Is $a \equiv b \pmod {100}$ always true?

The first thing that came in my mind was [*Fermat's Little Theorem*](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Little_Theorem). WLOG $a\ge b$. Since $(101,2)=1$, dividing both sides by $2^b$ gives $$2^{a-b}\equiv 1\pmod {101}$$ Also, $$2^{100}\equiv 1\pmod {101} $$
by Fermat's Little Theorem.

How should I continue?

Comment: The question is effectively asking about the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of $2 \bmod 101$. Since we know that $101$ is prime, all orders divide $100$. Thus we want to know if $\text{ord}_{101}(2) = 100$ - that is, whether $2$ is a [primitive root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n) $\bmod 101$.

Answer (score 2):

By repeatedly squaring and reducing modulo $101$ we obtain
$$\eqalign{
  2^2&\equiv4\cr
  2^4&\equiv16\cr
  2^5&\equiv32\cr
  2^{10}&\equiv1024\equiv14\cr
  2^{20}&\equiv196\equiv-6\cr
  2^{40}&\equiv36\cr
  2^{50}&\equiv504\equiv-1\ .\cr}$$
Thus
$$2^{20}\not\equiv1\quad\hbox{and}\quad 2^{50}\not\equiv1\ ;$$
this is sufficient to show that $2^k$ can never be $1$ modulo $101$ for $1\le k<100$, and so in your problem, $a-b$ must be a multiple of $100$.

For the theory behind this, see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866901/primitive-roots-modulo-n/866919#866919).